# Fetching an API with multiple params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, axios

I have an URL and I am trying to pass multiple params into it and fetch it with each param in the same call to provide the data for each param.
For example: param_1 has different data from param_2, and I am trying to fetch both datas in the same axios call.

```
const data_1 = "param_1";
const data_2 = "param_2";

const URL = 'http://google_services?gls_url=${data_1}'
const URL = 'http://google_services?gls_url=${data_2}'

useEffect(()=> {
 axios(URL).then(res => res.data);
},[])
```

Comment: unless you're in control of the back-end, what you're describing needs to be handled explicitly by the back-end within 1 api call. Otherwise you need to call the API twice

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to insert `data_1` and `data_1` into the same url, I'd suggest to pass a different parameter that you call `data`, as a `useState`. Now you can set `data` to data_1 or data_2 according to when you need it.

Comment: I would appreciate an example in code

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question or what the problem is, but I suppose, this is what you are searching for:

```js
const data_1 = "param_1";
const data_2 = "param_2";

const URL = 'http://google_services'

useEffect(()=> {
 axios
 .get(URL, {
  params: {
    gls_url: data_1,
    photo: "34433",
  }
  })
 .then(res => res.data);
},[])
```

But u don't know where you need data_2

Comment: im trying to fetch "gls_url: data_2" instead of  "photo: 34433" in your logic?

Comment: Then just remove the 'photo: "34433"' and add gls_url: data_2.
But I see, you want multiple data for the same parameter?

Comment: yes exactly, it has to be the same parameter, I can't have two parameters there, it won't work. i removed the photo parameter because it was making the confusion

Comment: Well if you don't have any control over the api's code itself, you will need to make 2 API calls